# jQuery not working on pages

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm making a real estate website. I'm using a paid service that shows listings on my pages. My website becomes a sub domain of the paid service website and it dynamically pulls my header and footer wrappers. The URL looks like this - www.mywebsite.listingswebsite.com The page looks like this:

```
My Header
Their listing content (that I can't control)
My Footer
```

I'm learning jQuery and using the prepend / append functions in order to add things to a page. The problem is, prepend works on every page that is mine, but not on pages that I can't control.

```
$('#MyDIV').prepend('<p>Text</p>');
```

Works fine. But when I try to do it on a page where my website becomes a sub domain, it doesn't work.

```
$('#TheirDIV').prepend('<p>Text</p>');
```

My guess is that the service is pulling my header and footer wrappers after their content loads, so it's too late. Any solutions to this?

Comment: It's probably because their content is in an Iframe pointing to a different domain, and the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) is preventing your Javascript code from interacting with the Iframe's content.

Comment: Have you checked for any errors in the console?

Answer (score 2):

The listings are probably being displayed in an iframe which is not going to be affected at all by any code that you attach before or after. It is basically displaying a different webpage within your webpage. Without seeing the code of the actual page however this is just an educated guess at best.